# "How far can you go up" or "how far can you come up" when talking about price?

Tags: word-choice

Could you tell me if I have to use how *far can you go up* or *how far can come up* when talking about price?

I would do the job for $200. How far can you **go**/**come** up?

Comment: I think the metaphoric reference to *possible [vertical] distance to travel* is inappropriate for the context, so I don't see much point in trying to figure out the most idiomatic way to phrase it. Particularly when many people routinely use roundabout phrasing *and* unusual syntax & vocabulary when negotiating prices. Just go for clarity, and ask directly - *How much are you willing to pay?* or *How much can you afford?* (or perhaps *What's your budget?*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When haggling colloquially, the phrase used to ask this would be "**How high** can/could/will/would you go [for X item]?"

> I think that my TV is worth more than that.  How high would you go for it?

Your sentence is a little different, as it asks how *little* they would do the work for:

> I would do the job for $200. How low would you go?